# "Including" disambiguation

Tags: parts-of-speech

This sentence is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website):

> A website is a collection of related web pages, including multimedia content, typically identified with a common name, and published on at least one web server.

Is the word ***including*** mentioned in the above text
a) the present participle of the standard verb "include"
b) the gerund of the standard verb "include"
c) the substitution form of the standard verb "include"
or
d) an adverb?

Comment: I edited your question to include a link to the source material. (And to put the quotation in a block quote.)

Comment: Look up the word in a good dictionary. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Including*** is used as a **preposition** here.

> You use **including** to introduce examples of people or things that are part of the group of people or things that you are talking about.
>
> *...many conditions, including allergies, hyperactivity and tooth decay.*
> ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/including))

See also other gerunds used as prepositions: e.g., *excluding, excepting, barring*.

Comment: Or a present participle. Just wanted to double check.

Answer (score -1):

", including multimedia content," is a (free modifier) parenthetical (adverbial) phrase.  'Including' is here an active (present) participle (not a gerund).  The addition of this phrase is a short-cut way of saying "A website includes multimedia content."

I'm not familiar with the term 'substitutive verb'.  The participle "including" is a non-finite form of the verb, so when it lacks an auxiliary verb it equates to "to include", making it a gerund (noun), but in adverbial use the auxiliary (a form of 'be' matching the main tense) is simply assumed, so it is not a gerund -- a noun phrase is never adverbial (unless it is temporal, in which case a preposition can be assumed; but I digress).

{Regarding the other answer: Just because a word precedes a noun phrase does not make it a preposition.}